# Unable to start a VM image on VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I am unable to start any Ubuntu VM image that I create using the VirtualBox that I have installed on my PC.

For example, I create a new VM -> select 64 bit Ubuntu -> allocate 1024 MB RAM -> Create a Virtual Hard drive now -> etc etc and finish up till the end. When I click on start I get the following error dialog immediately:

[image: Error]

I am using a Windows 7 - 64 bit machine with 4 GB RAM. The VirtualBox version that I have installed is **4.3.16** which happens to be the latest. I also tried with previous versions but with no success.

I also confirmed that the Virtualization option is enabled in the BIOS Menu (so that doesn't seem to be the problem).

The error log messages generated in the log file are as follows :

```
1660.1664: Log file opened: 4.3.16r95972 g_hStartupLog=0000000000000014 g_uNtVerCombined=0x611db110
1660.1664: Calling main()
1660.1664: SUPR3HardenedMain: pszProgName=VirtualBox fFlags=0x2
1660.1664: SUPR3HardenedMain: Respawn #1
1660.1664: System32:  \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32
1660.1664: WinSxS:    \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\winsxs
1660.1664: ProgDir:   \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Program Files
1660.1664: ComDir:    \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Program Files\Common Files
1660.1664: ProgDir32: \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Program Files (x86)
1660.1664: ComDir32:  \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
1660.1664: '\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe' has no   imports
1660.1664: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 0 (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe)
1660.1664: supR3HardNtEnableThreadCreation:
1660.1664: supR3HardNtDisableThreadCreation: pvLdrInitThunk=0000000077afb800 pvNtTerminateThread=0000000077b20ae0
1660.1664: supR3HardenedWinDoReSpawn(1): New child 1508.bbc [kernel32].
1660.1664: supR3HardenedWinPurifyChild: PebBaseAddress=000007fffffda000 cbPeb=0x380
1660.1664: supR3HardNtPuChFindNtdll: uNtDllParentAddr=0000000077ad0000 uNtDllChildAddr=0000000077ad0000
1660.1664: supR3HardNtPuChTriggerInitialImageEvents: uLdrInitThunk=0000000077afb800 uNtTerminateThread=0000000077b20ae0
1660.1664: supR3HardNtDisableThreadCreation: pvLdrInitThunk=0000000077afb800 pvNtTerminateThread=0000000077b20ae0
1660.1664: supR3HardNtPuChTriggerInitialImageEvents: mapping view of ntdll.dll[2nd]
1660.1664: supR3HardNtPuChTriggerInitialImageEvents: ntdll.dll[2nd] mapped at 00000000001a0000 LB 0x1aa000
1660.1664: supR3HardNtPuChTriggerInitialImageEvents: mapping view of kernel32.dll
1660.1664: supR3HardNtPuChTriggerInitialImageEvents: kernel32.dll mapped at 00000000779b0000 LB 0x11f000
1660.1664: supR3HardNtPuChTriggerInitialImageEvents: mapping view of KernelBase.dll
1660.1664: supR3HardNtPuChTriggerInitialImageEvents: KernelBase.dll mapped at 000007fefd920000 LB 0x6c000
1660.1664: supR3HardNtPuChTriggerInitialImageEvents: Startup delay kludge #1: 31 ms
1660.1664: supR3HardNtEnableThreadCreation:
1660.1664: supHardNtVpScanVirtualMemory: enmKind=CHILD_PURIFICATION
1660.1664:  *0000000000000000-fffffffffffeffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1660.1664:  *0000000000010000-fffffffffffeffff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1660.1664:  *0000000000030000-000000000002bfff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
1660.1664:   0000000000034000-0000000000027fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1660.1664:  *0000000000040000-000000000003efff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
```

I have also tried opening Ubuntu.iso image and a pre built Ubuntu.vdi image but no matter what I try I keep getting the same error. Could someone please help me in resolving this ?

Comment: where did you download the iso file ? please try this one : http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=DE&version=14.04.1&architecture=amd64   it works for me. The virtualization option in bios only allows you to create 64bit versions, if it's not enabled you only see the 32bit option when creating the vb. Are you sure you are mounting it correctly using VBox?

Comment: @RayofCommand - I have used the same iso file (**ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso** from the link that you have mentioned).  Also, I followed these steps to mount it (VM settings -> Storage -> Controller: IDE -> CD/DVD Drive and selecting the iso). But the error persists. Is there any other way to mount it ? 

Also while searching on Google, I came across a post which suggested the error could be resolved by disabling the Network Adapter in Netowrk option of VM settings. I tried that as well but it didnt work :(

Comment: no I think you do it correctly. Do you have network Adapters enabled? If yes, please disable and try to start.

Comment: @RayofCommand - Please see my comment above. I edited it with the Network Adapter part as well.

Comment: I remember myself having the same error code for that ubuntu version. It was only happening to 4.3.16 , I installed 4.2.16 and it magically worked. You said you already tried earlier versions. Please try 4.2.16 which works form e at the same setup..

Comment: Wow !! Thanks a lot ! 4.2.16 did the trick .. I had tried versions 4.3.14 and few older versions of 3.xx but those had not worked .. but apparently 4.2.16 has some secret driver settings in it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same Issue. I used 4.3.16 and tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit). 
It was not working giving me the same errorcode 0x80004005.

I remember that I had that working some time ago using Virtualbox Version 4.2.16, I found the old installer and installed it. It magically worked.

So if someone knows WHY this works for the given setup please edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a iso image of Ubuntu, you have to enter the VirtualBox menu and add a new CD-ROM device giving the path of the iso image.

Comment: Yes .. Like I mentioned in the question, I tried that but when I start it, I get the same error dialog.

Answer (score -1):

After I changed (/upgraded) the Motherboard and CPU of my PC, I get the same error even enabled the virtualization mode of CPU in BIOS.
Then by searching the Internet, I get the info said that the instruction set may have been changed because of changing the Motherboard and CPU.

We can try the following solutions:

1. Export the virtual machines in current VBox to backup our virtual PCs.
2. Re-install the latest VBox software.
3. (Optional) Try to import the .ova img from the first step into the new VBox, and check if it works or not. If yes, good luck. You have done, otherwise going down.
4. Re-install the OS of Host PC finally. I have tested that the .ova img from the first step with VBox version 4.3.28 can be imported into my friend's VBox on his PC, and also the vm system of mine in his VBox started correctly.